# Electric Smoker Trips GFCI

Tags: electrical, receptacle, gfci

My outside outlet is tied to a GFCI receptacle. When I plug in my smoker, the GFCI TRIPS.  What con I do to avoid this besides running an extension cord to another receptacle (inside the apartment)?

Comment: Sounds like you have a ground fault in the smoker and the GFCI is protecting you. Plugging it into a non-GFCI outlet may allow it to work, but will expose you to a potential shock hazard. It's possible (but less likely) that the GFCI is bad, but I'd check the smoker for wiring faults (or water intrusion if it's kept outside)

Comment: I'd run an extension cord and plug it into a different GFCI in your house, e.g. Kitchen or bathroom.   If it still trips, it's the appliance.

Comment: Nothing else running off that outlet trips the GFCI?

Answer (score 3):

The GFCI is **tripping for a reason**. Older ones sometimes tripped for false positives, but that's very rare with modern fuses/interrupters.

Especially if the outlet interrupts *with the same appliance every time* then the problem is the *appliance* not the *outlet.* Do some troubleshooting on the grill to find out if you can repair it, or need to replace it. It might be that the grill is operating as it was designed to, and it's simply drawing more current than is safe for a typical outlet.

Meanwhile, go thank the GFCI for doing its job and saving your life/apartment.

Comment: A GFCI shouldn't trip on current alone.  But regardless, a 25-A smoker on a 15-A circuit (as an example) is certainly a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

I viewed a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k68VsiUnGag) that showed a fix...take a propane torch and torch the heating element to eliminate any moisture/buildup on it. A lot of viewers said this worked...am going to try this tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

Just confirming you have 2 potentials:

- Smoker actually has a Ground Fault
- GFCI is bad

None of which are a good thing. Determine the smoker is good by testing on a known good GFCI outlet (no extension) to eliminate the easiest fix, changing the GFCI. If the smoker is bad, try to identify the damage and and repair or replace it.

Answer (score 0):

That smoker coil acts like a short when it starts, same reason large electric motors have starter units - to limit voltage drop on the line due to amperage surge.  When you turn it on there is a large current rush and voltage drop, much higher than the steady state operating amperage. Once the current stabilizes it should run OK, problem is getting it started.  I had to run a heavy extension cord inside to a non-GFI plug.

Comment: Shorting hot to neutral won't trip a GFCI - currents are still equal.  Also resistive heaters don't have inrush.